# What is the correct way for saving a cryptographic key?

Tags: c#, encryption, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
```

And either one of these:

```
byte[] Csp = rsa.ExportCspBlob(true);
RSAParameters parameters = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
```

What is the correct way to save them, and what file extension should be used?
Note: I'm not referring to how to encrypt them. Just how to store them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use the `RSACryptoServiceProvider.PersistKeyInCsp = true`. Make sue that the `CspParameters.KeyContainerName` contains a unique identifiable name for they key.

To transfer the public key around, use the export to `Xml` methods.